# Phpmyadmin error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I recently installed Mariadb with PhpMyAdmin and it seems to be working fine except when I need to browse a database.

This is the error I get when browsing a column:

“Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable”

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/omy08s

When I browse a column it does show the content but it gives me the error each time I look inside a column.

Can it be something permission based thats not setup right?

MariaDB Version: 10.4.6
Ubuntu Version: 18.04.02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu repositories have an old phpmyadmin, not fully compatible with default PHP release (7.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 distribuiton).

To get rid of this error just install a newer phpmyadmin from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

You might want to follow this as a reference: https://devanswers.co/problem-php-7-2-phpmyadmin-warning-in-librariessql-count/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated it and it seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: Please follow my advice, will make the question more useful for the whole Community.